# No default value in username while trying to create a user in nestjs

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, backend, nestjs

Although I am able to perfectly perform GET requests I have trouble sending a POST request using form data.

And although I am able to successfully send a POST request using form-urlencoded and raw JSON I am having trouble dealing with form data.

While trying to send a post request to my db I seem to get an error which says: `ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'username' doesn't have a default value`
even though I provide a value for it in postman.

Below is the code for my repo:

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { CreateUserDTO } from './dto/create-user.dto';

@EntityRepository(User)

export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
    getUser() {
        const query = this.createQueryBuilder('user');
        return query.getMany();
    }
createUser(createUserDTO: CreateUserDTO) {
    const {username, email } = createUserDTO;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log('Repo', username);

    // tslint:disable-next-line:new-parens
    const newuser = new User(); //edited after Natan's comment
    newuser.username = username;
    newuser.email = email;

    return newuser.save();
    }
}
```

This is my entity code:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;
}
```

and my post request in the controller:

```
@Post()
    createUser(
        @Body() createUserDTO: CreateUserDTO,
    ) {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.log('creating new user', createUserDTO);
        return this.userService.createUser(createUserDTO);
    }
```

And here is a picture of the post request in postman:
[image]

Comment: What database are you working with?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel working with mysql

Answer (score 1):

You must use `()` to instantiate a class in TS, like:

```js
createUser(createUserDTO: CreateUserDTO) {
    const {username, email } = createUserDTO;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log('Repo', username);

    // tslint:disable-next-line:new-parens
    const newuser = new User(); // <- HERE IS new User()
    newuser.username = username;
    newuser.email = email;

    return newuser.save();
}
```

Comment: Hello Natan, I just tried it out but it doesnt seem to be the error. I keep on getting the same error.

Comment: I double checked seems that you're sending user data as query param and receiving them as request body. You've to change how you make your post request, to send a JSON on request body

Comment: Try this curl: curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/user' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "Karma",
    "email": "karma@gmail.com"
}'

Comment: Just to clarify i am able to perform get requests and works completely fine, but the problem seems to be with post.

Comment: here is what i got after running it:  

`[{"id":1,"username":"karma","email":"kzoepa@gmail.com"}]curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  --header  
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '  
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  --data-raw  
[1/2]:  "username": "Karma" --> <stdout>  
--_curl_-- "username": "Karma"  
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '  
  
[2/2]:  "email": "karma@gmail.com"  --> <stdout>  
--_curl_-- "email": "karma@gmail.com"  
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: gmail.com"`